# how to bulkify the trigger

Tags: trigger

I have 3 objects appointment, invoice and revenue. Invoice has a look up to appointment. There are some appointments that have an invoice and some appointments that do not have an invoice. There is a common field in both objects named ecode.

My requirement is that the revenue object will have the value of the ecode inserted into it. If the ecode is present in the invoice record then the revenue calculation should happen from invoice object. If the ecode is not present in the invoice record, then the calculation needs to happen from the appointment record.

I have written the trigger also.

When I am performing the action manually the trigger is working fine. When I am uploading through data-loader, since I've used `invoicelist.size()` whose value is greater than zero, the calculation is going to the second loop.

How do I solve this issue with my trigger?

```
trigger Revenue_calculations on Revenue__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<id,String>reids=new Map<id,String>();   
    set<string>ecode=new set<string>();
    set<integer>Bmonth=new set<integer>(); 
    List<Revenue__c> revenue=new List<Revenue__c>();
    List<Invoice__c>invoice=new List<Invoice__c>();
    List<Appointment__c >appointment= new List<Appointment__c>();
    List<Appointment__c >appsointment2= new List<Appointment__c>();
    Decimal InvoiceFinalamount;   
    String clientname;
    String talentname;
    Decimal amount;

    for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){
        ecode.add(re.ECode__c);
    }

    appointment= [select Contact_Talent__r.name,DOJ__c,Last_Working_Date__c,Employer__r.name, ECode__c  from Appointment__c where ECode__c IN:ecode];
    system.debug('***ecode**'+ecode);
    system.debug('&&Bmonth&&'+Bmonth);
    invoice=[select id,name,Emp_Code__c,Sub_Total__c,Status_of_Invoice__c,T from Invoice__c where Emp_Code__c IN:ecode AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Billing_Month__c) IN:Bmonth ];
    system.debug('%%%invlist%%'+invoice);
    system.debug('invlist.size()'+invoice.size());

    if(invoice.size()==0 ){
        appsointment=[select HR_Initial_BillRate__c,Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c,ECode__c from Appointment__c where ECode__c IN:ecode ];
        system.debug('apps2***'+appointment2);

        for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){
            amount=0;

            for(Appointment__c ap:appsointment2){

                if(ap.ECode__c ==re.ECode__c){
                    system.debug('inside new loop'+re.ECode__c);
                    amount= ap.HR_Initial_BillRate__c*66;
                    re.Revenue_Without_ST__c=amount;
                    re.invoice_exist__c =false;
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    if( invoice.size()!=0){

        for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){   
            ecode.add(re.ECode__c);
            Bmonth.add(re.Salary_Processed_Month__c.month());                
            integer count=0;
            InvoiceFinalamount=0;
            Integer count1=0;
            system.debug('++invlist size++'+invoice.size());

            for(Invoice__c Inv:invoice){
                system.debug('^^Inv.Emp_Code__c^^'+Inv.Emp_Code__c);
                system.debug('22Inv.Type_of_Invoices__c22'+Inv.Type_of_Invoices__c);
                system.debug('$$re.Invoice_Type__c$$'+Inv.Billing_Month__c);

                if(re.Invoice_Type__c==Inv.Type_of_Invoices__c ) {

                    if(re.ECode__c==Inv.Emp_Code__c && re.Salary_Processed_Month__c.month()==Inv.Billing_Month__c.month()&& re.Salary_Processed_Month__c.year()==Inv.Billing_Month__c.year() ){
                        count=count+1;
                        SYSTEM.DEBUG('Inv.Sub_Total__c+++++ '+Inv.Sub_Total__c);
                        InvoiceFinalamount+= Inv.Sub_Total__c*72;
                    }

                }

                system.debug('CCCcountCCC'+count);
                system.debug('$$InvoiceFinalamount$$'+InvoiceFinalamount);
            }

            for(Appointment__c ap :appointment){  

                if(re.ECode__c == ap.ECode__c ){
                    re.Talent_Name__c=ap.Contact_Talent__r.name;
                    re.Client_Name__c=ap.Employer__r.name;
                    re.DOJ__c=ap.DOJ__c;
                    re.Last_Working_Date__c=ap.Last_Working_Date__c;
                    re.Actual_PO_value__c =ap.HR_Initial_BillRate__c;
                    re.Rate_pattern__c=ap.HR_Rate_Pattern__c;
                    re.Currency_Type__c=ap.Currency_Type__c;
                }
            }
            re.invoice_exist__c =true;
            re.Revenue_Without_ST__c=InvoiceFinalamount;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: as Crmprogdev stated in the current state of the code you provided it would require some time to someone to understand what every variable means.  

I would suggest as a lecture Clean Code by Robert Cecil Martin. It will help you write higher quality and more easily to understand code.  

As a general rule of thumb try to use names in the variables that describes them this way you avoid having other people to guess or for you to add comments.

Answer (score 1):

First: you'd do yourself and anyone trying to help you a big favor if you used meaningful names in your variables.

```
Map<id,String>reids=new Map<id,String>(); // revenueIdToWhat?  
set<string>ecode=new set<string>(); // What is an ecode? Be descriptive
set<integer>Bmonth=new set<integer>(); // Is this the month of the year?
List<Revenue__c> revlist=new List<Revenue__c>(); //Just name this revenue
List<Invoice__c>invlist=new List<Invoice__c>(); just name this invoice
List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>invlinelist=new List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>(); //invoiceLineItem 
List<SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c >apps= new List<SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c>(); // appointments
List<SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c >apps2= new List<SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c>(); // try appointmentsTwo, appointmentsB or something else more meaningful
```

If you're having a problem with your trigger because you have invoices!=0, then you need to add an `else{` section to handle those and keep track of the invoices that were `=0` (for example, add them to a map of Revenue__c.Id to invoice record id - or vice versa) to make certain that all of the records in your trigger were handled.

The way your trigger is currently written, it's difficult for someone to come in and invest the time trying to sort it out for you. Make it more readable by using proper indentation. That will help you as well in sorting out the issues you're having with it. Also add lots of debug statements to help you sort out what's happening inside of it.

To summarize the details in your question:

- Invoice has a look up to appointment.
- Revenue is to have the value of ecode inserted
- If the ecode not in invoice record, use ecode from appointment record

Your query for appointment doesn't include the related invoice record which you could easily obtain. You could either get it using Invoice__r or use a subquery. If you use Invoice__r, you still don't get its ecode, so a subquery might be a preferable way to go.

Once you have the results of that query, you can easily create a map of ecode to  Appointment, ecode to Invoice and ApointmentId to Invoice for all the appointment records for which Invoices have already been created with ecodes.

For the ones which haven't, you'll know you need to create them. In that way, ALL of your calculations for Revenue are created in the SAME loop. If the look-up from your maps doesn't return a result, then you'll know you need to create a new invoice for the ecode that appears to be contained in Revenue (based on what I can tell from reading your code). Just use your maps to pull out the relevant data and do the calculations.

I recommend you create test data and use Test Driven Design to test your code for this as you move through your development of this trigger. Create multiple records that you can query and work on blocks of code that you can test in "chunks". Start using a single record, then move to multiple records once you have a single record working of each type.

Comment: sir i have modified the code and gave description about my requirement also can you please help?

Comment: I've formatted your code to show you what it ***should*** look like so that it's easily readable and understandable. I see that you've not bothered to follow my suggestions to try and make your variable names more descriptive. I'm going to edit my answer to tell you how to approach solving your issue which is a matter of relating Invoice to Appointment by using maps, then iterating on the map keyset since you have a look-up from one to the other.